# Bootstrap 4 nav collapsing animation stopping for a split second when opening, ok closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When you expand the menu it slides down, stops for a split second and the continues. Sliding back up seems to be fine though but not as smooth when opening.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  left: auto;
}

.navbar-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 20;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar-menu {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

.navbar-menu .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #351C81;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 35px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar-menu .title {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: -17px;
  }
}

.navbar-menu.open .title {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 17px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #351C81;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2),
.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 6px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 6px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0B0039, #281663 65%, #2B176B);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #68E0CA;
}

.navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav {
  transition: all 0.25s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="500">
  <div class="navbar-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navigation">
    <span class="title">Menu</span>
    <div class="navbar-toggler">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/quiz">Quiz</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/advice">Advise</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a lot of unnecessary absolute positioning, both to have items fill the screen and be centered in other elements. This was preventing Bootstrap's toggle JS from properly recognizing what the height of the expanding element should be.

Instead of having the `.navbar-collapse` absolute positioned to always take up your window, the content inside of it should be the height of your window - I used `height: 100vh` on `.navbar-nav` to do this.

Additionally, since `.navbar-nav` is already a `display: flex` element in Bootstrap, I removed your absolute positioning from it and added `justify-content: center` to vertically center the list elements in it.

Here's a diff of my changes to your CSS (yours on the left):
[image]

And working example below:

```css
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.navbar.fixed-top {
  left: auto;
}

.navbar-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 17px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 20;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar-menu {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

.navbar-menu .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #351C81;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 35px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .navbar-menu .title {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    margin-right: -17px;
  }
}

.navbar-menu.open .title {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 17px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #351C81;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2),
.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 6px;
}

.navbar-menu .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 12px;
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 6px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.navbar-menu.open .navbar-toggler span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 6px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#0B0039, #281663 65%, #2B176B);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  color: #68E0CA;
}

.navbar-collapse.show .navbar-nav {
  transition: all 0.25s;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="500">
  <div class="navbar-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navigation">
    <span class="title">Menu</span>
    <div class="navbar-toggler">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navigation">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/quiz">Quiz</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/advice">Advise</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great and works! however only works when at top of page, the menu link is fixed so when scroll down the page and click the link it does not show as expanded at top? hence the position i set... you know a fix for this? im having a play now but if you know of one would be great

Comment: example add: <div style="height: 1000px;"></div> to the end of the html and you will see what i mean

Comment: @James Sure - you just need to fix `.navbar-collapse`. Add these rules: `position: fixed; top: 0;  left: 0; right: 0;`

Comment: Yep perfect mate! worked a treat! thanks for your help bro! really appreciate it.